# Replace white spaces only in part of the string

Tags: java, string

I have a String like

```
"This is apple tree"
```

I want to remove the white spaces available until the word apple.After the change it will be like

```
"Thisisapple tree"
```

I need to achieve this in single replace command combined with regular expressions.

Comment: so basically concatenating all until the last space, isnt it?

Comment: I need 1 million dollars

Comment: No,i'm not worried about the index of spaces,it has to handle following scenario also."This is apple tree with large branches" is changed to "Thisisapple tree with large branches"

Comment: I came to write an answer but now I am too busy reading comments

Comment: Until the word apple? Does this mean that if the sentence if `"This is an apple tree, not an orange tree"`, the ouput would be `"Thisisanapple tree, not an orange tree"`? What if the word apple doesn't appear?

Comment: This is actually not a bad question. +1 from me.

Comment: Please read comments and try to edit your question to be clearly understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now it looks like you may be looking for

```
String s = "This is apple tree";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\G(\\S+)(?<!(?<!\\S)apple)\\s", "$1"));
```

Output: `Thisisapple tree`.

Explanation:

- `\G` represents either end of previous match or start of input (`^`) if there was no previous match yet (when we are attempting to find first match)
- `\S+` represents one or more non-whitespace characters (to match words, including non-alphabetic characters like `'` or punctuation)
- `(?<!(?<!\\S)apple)\\s` negative-look-behind will prevent accepting whitespace which has `apple` before it (I added another negative-look-behind before `apple` to make sure that it doesn't have any non-whitespace which ensures that this is not part of some other word)
- `$1` in replacement represents match from group 1 (the one from `(\S+)`) which represents word. So we are replacing word and spaces with only word (effectively removing spaces)

---

WARNING: This solution assumes that

- sentence doesn't start with space,
- words can be separated with only one space.

If we want to get rid of this assumptions we would need something like:

```
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("^\\s+|\\G(\\S+)(?<!(?<!\\S)apple)\\s+", "$1"));
```

- `^\s+` will allow us to match spaces at beginning of string (and replace them with content of group 1 (word) which in this case will be empty, so we will simply remove these whitespaces)
- `\s+` at the end allows us to match word and one or more spaces after it (to remove them)

Comment: Wow !!,Thanks a lot Pshemo,this expression is what i need..Thanks a lot again !!!

Comment: It also omitting any no of spaces coming after the tree ..Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: @Raghavan Yes, that is why I used `\G` here (end of previous match).

Comment: I struggled a lot for getting this correct expression

Comment: Doesnt the question demand the spaces to be available only till the word "apple"? This code fails for "This is apple plant not an orange tree"

Comment: @AnkitKhettry then look behind and prevent apple before the space: `"\\G(\\S+)(?<!apple)\\s"`

Comment: @AnkitKhettry You may be right. I read to many comments and forgot about main question... anyway zapl provided solution for that (I would just change `(?<!apple)` to `(?<!\bapple)` or `(?<!(?<!\S)apple)` to make sure that we are matching vs `apple` and not word which ends with `apple`.

Comment: @Ankit Yeah,i can make minute modification , according to my requirement.But where it stucked was to get this main expression.Thanks both of you..

Comment: This is cool :) I wasn't aware we could do so much using regex. +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

A single replace() is unlikely to solve your problem. You could do something like this..

```
String s[] = "This is an apple tree, not an orange tree".split("apple");
System.out.println(new StringBuilder(s[0].replace(" ","")).append("apple").append(s[1]));
```

Comment: Thanks @Ankit,This will work,but i have restriction of not to have more than 2 lines

Comment: Edited. If it helps you :)

Comment: The above method can actually be achievd in one single statement too. But will be difficult to read

Answer (score 0):

This is achived via **lookahead assertion**, like this:

```
    String str = "This is an apple tree";
    System.out.println(str.replaceAll(" (?=.*apple)", ""));
```

It means: replace all spaces in front of which there anywhere word **apple**

Comment: fails for `"This is an apple plant, not an apple tree"`

Comment: nope, working correctly =)
`Thisisanappleplant,notanapple tree`

Comment: Yeah,but i'm trying now to add with index of it's occurance.Thanks @zapl

Comment: did you need the `Thisisanapple plant, not an apple tree`?
And why someone give my answer -1???

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a regular expression you could try:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("^(.*?\\bapple\\b)(.*)$").matcher("This is an apple but this apple is an orange");
System.out.println((!matcher.matches()) ? "No match" : matcher.group(1).replaceAll(" ", "") + matcher.group(2));
```

This checks that "apple" is an individual word and not just part of another word such as "snapple".  It also splits at the first use of "apple".